# How to modify model in odoo, such that modifications can be discarded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, undo, odoo-11

Normally when editing a model in Odoo, one can click the Discard button to revert all changes.

Now I have a button that performs some modifications on the model, for example it clears a field. Sadly this change is not reverted when clicking Discard. So I assume that the change I make to the model in code is directly persisted. How do I modify a model in a way, that the change is not directly persisted before clicking Save?

In other frameworks one often modifies a working-copy of a model, which can simply be discarded or applied to the real model. How does the Discard mechanism in Odoo work?

**Example**

In my view I have a button:

```
<header>
    <button string="Clear Filter" type="object" name="clear_filter"/>
</header>
```

And in my model I clear the filter like so:

```
def clear_filter(self):
    for record in self:
        record.filter = None
```

This works, but the modification of the field is directly persisted and cannot be discarded.

Comment: What is your use case? You can use `onchange` but there might be a better way depending on your use case.

Comment: A button call in Odoo will either call a create or write. Both calls will save everything into db.

Comment: Well I guess I have to live with this. My use case is that I modify some records on button click (e.g. add records to many2many, clear the filter as shown above). But these actions cannot be undone which breaks with the normal user expectations